# Rewrite a postscript macro in LaTeX

Tags: macros, pstricks, calculations

I wrote a macro in PSTricks with which the number pi is calculated approximately with the so-called "Monte-Carlo-Method".

A table will be setup with two randomly chosen numbers x and y  (each of them between 0 and 1). Each of them has a seperate counter depending if x^2 + y^2 > 1 or x^2 + y^2 <= 1
Now I'd like to rewrite that in LaTeX/L3.
Is there anybody to give me a hint how to start?
Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dvipsnames,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}

\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{}{colorF}[blue]{\pst@getcolor{#1}\psk@colorF}
\define@key[psset]{}{colorT}[red]{\pst@getcolor{#1}\psk@colorT}
\define@key[psset]{}{colorPi}[green]{\pst@getcolor{#1}\psk@colorPi}
\psset{colorF=blue,colorT=red,colorPi=green}
%
\def\psRandomPiTable{\pst@object{psRandomPiTable}}
\def\psRandomPiTable@i#1{%
 \pst@killglue
  \addbefore@par{colorF=DarkBlue,colorT=BrickRed,colorPi=Green,fontscale=7}%
  \begin@SpecialObj
  \addto@pscode{
        /s1 { /Symbol findfont \psk@fontscale\space 4 add scalefont setfont } bind def
        /s2 { \psk@PSfont findfont \psk@fontscale\space scalefont setfont } bind def
        /s3 { \psk@PSfont findfont \psk@fontscale\space 4 add scalefont setfont } bind def
        /zaehlerT 0 def
        /zaehlerF 0 def
        /dec 3 def
        /ru \psk@fontscale\space 0.5 add def
        /re 30 def
        realtime srand Rand pop
    4 dict begin
       1 1 #1 {
                /i ED
                /x Rand def
                /y Rand def
                /r { x dup mul y dup mul add sqrt } bind def
                s2
                /showvalue { 10 dec exp mul round 10 dec exp div 9 string cvs dot2comma show } bind def
                0 i 1 add ru mul neg moveto %
                i 3 string cvs show
                re i 1 add ru mul neg moveto %
                x showvalue
                2 re mul i 1 add ru mul neg moveto %
                y showvalue
                gsave
                r 1 lt
                    { /zaehlerF zaehlerF 1 add def \pst@usecolor\psk@colorF 3 re mul i 1 add ru mul neg moveto }
                    { /zaehlerT zaehlerT 1 add def \pst@usecolor\psk@colorT 4 re mul i 1 add ru mul neg moveto }
                ifelse %
                r showvalue
                r 1 lt
                    { 5 re mul i 1 add ru mul neg moveto (Nr. ) show zaehlerF 10 string cvs show }
                    { 5 re mul i 1 add ru mul neg moveto (Nr. ) show zaehlerT 10 string cvs show }
                ifelse %
                grestore
               } for
        gsave \pst@usecolor\psk@colorF \psk@PSfont findfont \psk@fontscale\space 4 add scalefont setfont
        2 re mul 0.4 ru mul neg moveto (Summe: ) show zaehlerF 10 string cvs show
        grestore
        gsave \pst@usecolor\psk@colorT\psk@PSfont findfont \psk@fontscale\space 4 add scalefont setfont
        4 re mul 0.4 ru mul neg moveto (Summe: ) show zaehlerT 10 string cvs show
        grestore
        gsave \pst@usecolor\psk@colorPi
        0 re mul 0.4 ru mul neg moveto s1 (\string\160 \string\273 ) show s3 4 zaehlerF i div mul 10 string cvs dot2comma show
        grestore
    end
  }%
  \end@SpecialObj
 \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\section*{$\pi$-Monte-Carlo}
\psRandomPiTable{100}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to reimplement this if you provided to original (infix) formulae.

Comment: I think I got the idea, by reading [here](http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/monte-carlo-circle).

Comment: @AlexG yes, that is it, in the code: 4 zaehlerF i div mul means 4*Z/N, in the example: 4*79/(79+21)=3,16

Answer (score 10, accepted):

E. g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*\piMC[1]{
  \pi_mc:n{#1}
}
\cs_new_nopar:Nn\pi_mc:n{
  \int_zero_new:N\l_M_int
  \prg_replicate:nn{#1}{
    \fp_compare:nNnT{rand()**2+rand()**2}<{1}{\int_incr:N\l_M_int}
  }
  \fp_eval:n{4*\int_use:N\l_M_int/#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 $N$ & $\pi$ \\\hline
 10    & \piMC{10}\\
 100   & \piMC{100}\\
 1000  & \piMC{1000}\\
 10000 & \piMC{10000}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

A refinement of the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mcpi {m}
 {
  \thomas_mcpi:n { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_thomas_mcpi_in_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomas_mcpi:n
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_thomas_mcpi_in_int
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   {
    \fp_compare:nNnT { rand()**2+rand()**2 }<{1}
     { \int_incr:N \l_thomas_mcpi_in_int }
  }
  \fp_eval:n { 4*\l_thomas_mcpi_in_int/#1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
 $N$ & $\pi$ \\\hline
 10    & \mcpi{10}\\
 100   & \mcpi{100}\\
 1000  & \mcpi{1000}\\
 10000 & \mcpi{10000}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a polished version of your code, more adherent to the guidelines. Note that `\thomas_mcpi:n` (your `\pi_mc:n`) should be “protected”, because it does an assignment; the int variable is better allocated outside the function.

Comment: @egreg Within a package, should *any* macro doing assignments be defined `\protected`, even those defined for internal use, or just those exposed to users of the package?

Comment: @AlexG Yes, it should

Comment: Ok, thank you, @egreg. But then, files like `latex.ltx` should be full of `\protected`.

Comment: @AlexG `\protected` wasn't normal back when latex.ltx was written. If it was written nowadays it would probably have many many `\protected` inside.

Answer (score 5):

Much much faster execution times can be obtained from using only TeX integers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintkernel}% for xintreplicate (which is a clone of the expl3 replicate)

\newcount\montecarlocount

\newcount\tmpcnta
\newcount\tmpcntb

\newcount\twotothefifteen
\twotothefifteen "8000 % 8*16**3 = 2**15 = 32768

\newcount\twotothethirty
\twotothethirty "40000000 % 4*16**7 = 2**30 = 1073741824

\makeatletter

\newcommand\onestep{%
  \tmpcnta\pdfuniformdeviate\twotothefifteen\relax
  \tmpcntb\pdfuniformdeviate\twotothefifteen\relax
  % A**2 + B**2 < R**2 ?
  \ifnum\numexpr\tmpcnta*\tmpcnta+\tmpcntb*\tmpcntb < \twotothethirty
    \advance\montecarlocount \@ne
  \fi
}%

\newcommand\piMC[1]{%
  \montecarlocount \z@
  \romannumeral\xintreplicate{#1}\onestep
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\numexpr4*\montecarlocount*65536/#1 sp\relax
}


\newcount\gtotalcount
\newcount\gmontecarlocount

\newcommand\piMCstart{%
    \global\gtotalcount\z@
    \global\gmontecarlocount\z@
}

\newcommand\piMCmore[2]{%
    \montecarlocount \z@
    \romannumeral\xintreplicate{#1}{\romannumeral\xintreplicate{#2}\onestep}%
    \global\advance\gtotalcount \numexpr#1*#2\relax
    \global\advance\gmontecarlocount\montecarlocount
    \strip@pt\dimexpr\numexpr4*\gmontecarlocount*65536/\gtotalcount sp\relax
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pdfsetrandomseed 12345 % nota bene: automatically global

\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
 $N$ & $\pi$ & hits & total\\\hline
 10    & \piMC{10}\\
 100   & \piMC{100}\\
 1000  & \piMC{1000}\\
 10000 & \piMC{10000}\\
 100000 & \piMCstart
          \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 % \romannumeral\xintreplicate{8}{+100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}
 %                                 &\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\}%
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a caveat though with using only random integers `<32768`...:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcount\indicatorcount
\begin{document}

% we count exactly all pairs (x,y) with
% 1) 0<= x < 32768, 0 <= y< 32768
% 2) x**2+y**2 < 2**30 = 1073741824

% for this given x we need to count how many
% y < 32768 are there with y**2 < Z = 2**30 - x**2
% This means that y**2 is at most Z - 1
% This means that y is at most sqrt(Z-1)
% This means that y is at most trunc(sqrt(Z-1))  (automatically < 32768)
% This means that there are exactly 1 + trunc(sqrt(Z-1)) solutions
% for each x.

% we can use sqrt() function in \xintiiexpr to get
% the truncated square root.

% We use \xintexpr syntax to do the computation in one line

\edef\zzz{\xintiiexpr 2**30-1\relax}% don't use \xinttheiiexpr, keep it in
                                % private, so faster
\edef\www{\xintiiexpr 2**15\relax}

\edef\totalnumberofsolutions
  {\xinttheiiexpr iter(0; (i=\www)?{abort}
                                   {@ + 1 + sqrt(\zzz - i**2)}
                        , i = 0++)\relax}

\totalnumberofsolutions\space pairs $(x, y)$ exist with verify
\begin{enumerate}
\item $0\leqslant x, y < 32768$,
\item $x^2 +y^2 < 32768^2$.
\end{enumerate}

This means that Monte Carlo methods using only \verb|\pdfuniformdeviate 32768|
will (slowly) give an approximation, not of $\pi$ but of:
% 4*\totalnumberofsolutions would go in \numexpr and create arithmetic overflow!
% so we can not do this: \xintTrunc{15}{4*\totalnumberofsolutions/1073741824}
% 268435456 = 1073741824/4
% so we do that:
\[\xintTrunc{15}{\totalnumberofsolutions/268435456}\dots\]
\end{document}
```

Then, I figured out to use random integers `<2**28` rather than `<2**15`. Note that internally the PDFTeX RNG works with 28bits integers. The point is that the code below still uses only TeX integers, but it exploits `\numexpr` ability to temporary switch to doubled-precision.

Thus, the code is not much slower than the earlier one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintkernel}% for xintreplicate (which is a clone of the expl3 replicate)

\newcount\montecarlocount

\newcount\tmpcnta
\newcount\tmpcntb
\newcount\tmpcntc
\newcount\tmpcntd

\newcount\maxrand
\newcount\threemaxrand

%% 16**7 = 2**28. The pdftex RNG works natively with 28bits integers
\maxrand "10000000 
\threemaxrand "30000000

% I considered using \maxint for increased precision in the comparison below
% but with \maxrand gives same result
\newcount\maxint
% % % 2**31 - 1 (8 times \cntc minus 1)
\maxint "7FFFFFFF 

\makeatletter

\newcommand\onestep{%
   \tmpcnta\pdfuniformdeviate\maxrand\relax % A
   \tmpcntb\pdfuniformdeviate\maxrand\relax % B
% \ifnum\tmpcnta<\tmpcntb % this would make A >= B in what follows
%     \tmpcntc\tmpcntb
%     \tmpcntb\tmpcnta
%     \tmpcnta\tmpcntc
% \fi % but we don't use it finally
% This is commented-out too, it compares A+B with 1.5M
%   \tmpcntc\tmpcnta
%   \advance\tmpcntc\tmpcntb  % A + B
%   \multiply\tmpcntc \tw@
%   \ifnum\tmpcntc<\threemaxrand
     \tmpcntd\maxrand                         % M
     \advance\tmpcntd-\tmpcntb                % D = M - B
       \ifnum\tmpcntd>\tmpcnta  %% always true if A = 0 !!
         \advance\montecarlocount \@ne        % M - B > A => A^2 + B^2 < M^2
       \else
         % here M <= A + B
         \tmpcntc\tmpcntb                     
         \advance\tmpcntc\maxrand             % C = M + B
         \ifnum % use temporary double precision!
% I considered using \maxint for increased precision but does not change result
                 \numexpr\maxrand*\tmpcnta/\tmpcntc       % A/(M + B) (is < 1)
                <\numexpr\maxrand*\tmpcntd/\tmpcnta\relax % (M - B)/A (is <= 1)
% the comparison will not be very precise when both A<<M+B and M-B<<A
% this can happen only if M-B<<M+B, i.e. for B close to M. 
% 
% If B is arranged to be <= A, both A and B are then close to M and A+B is close to
% 2M. To make sure this does not happen we could require A+B < 1.5 M
%             (if A+B>=1.5M, then A^2+B^2>M^2 ...)
%
% But in fact even without precautions same result was obtained...
% .. and we can gain 20% time be suppressing all precautions...
% seems that comparison above with 30bits is precise enough
% So I have commented out the code which made sure B<= A and A+B< 1.5M
         \advance\montecarlocount \@ne
         \fi
       \fi        
%  \fi
}%

\newcommand\piMC[1]{%
  \montecarlocount \z@
  \romannumeral\xintreplicate{#1}\onestep
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\numexpr4*\montecarlocount*65536/#1 sp\relax
}


\newcount\gtotalcount
\newcount\gmontecarlocount

\newcommand\piMCstart{%
    \global\gtotalcount\z@
    \global\gmontecarlocount\z@
}

\newcommand\piMCmore[2]{%
    \montecarlocount \z@
    \romannumeral\xintreplicate{#1}{\romannumeral\xintreplicate{#2}\onestep}%
    \global\advance\gtotalcount \numexpr#1*#2\relax
    \global\advance\gmontecarlocount\montecarlocount
    \strip@pt\dimexpr\numexpr4*\gmontecarlocount*65536/\gtotalcount sp\relax
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pdfsetrandomseed 12345 % nota bene: automatically global

\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
 $N$ & $\pi$ & hits & total\\\hline
 10    & \piMC{10}\\
 100   & \piMC{100}\\
 1000  & \piMC{1000}\\
 10000 & \piMC{10000}\\
 100000 & \piMCstart
          \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 % \romannumeral\xintreplicate{38}{+100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}
 %                                 &\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\}%
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount\\
 +100000 & \piMCmore{100}{1000}&\the\gmontecarlocount&\the\gtotalcount
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

I don't know the exact value of the limit to which it will (very slowly) converges, but it will be closer to Pi than the `3.141713824123144 . . .` above.

---

I ran the "big" code, with a variant which outputs to a file. At the end of the `10**9` trials (watch a Futurama episode while waiting) I got this

```
999990000: 3.141574507745077
999991000: 3.141574510170592
999992000: 3.141574484595877
999993000: 3.141574483021381
999994000: 3.141574581447489
999995000: 3.141574591872959
999996000: 3.141574582298329
999997000: 3.141574628723886
999998000: 3.141574595149190
999999000: 3.141574585574586
1000000000: 3.141574576000000
```

In contrast with the "small" code (using random ints `<32768`) I had gotten under same circumstances `3.141701276` after `10**9` random points. Clearly the `3.141574576` is much better from using random ints `< 268435456`.

It seems execution of the "big" code is only about `50%` slower than "small" code.

Comment: you once again thought a lot and were very successful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Here another approach to get the calculations interactively done by JavaScript within the PDF file. However one needs Adobe Reader to view the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eforms}
\begin{defineJS}{\myPi}
var r = 5;
var points_total = 0;
var points_inside = 0;
var rowA ="";
var f1 = this.getField("PiField");
while(1){
  points_total++;
  var x = Math.random()*r*2-r;
  var y = Math.random()*r*2-r;
  if (Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) < Math.pow(r,2))
    points_inside++;
  if (points_total \% 100 == 0)
    util.printf("\%,2 .9f",(4*points_inside/points_total))+"\\r";
  if (points_total == 1000)
  break;
  var row="Total "
    +util.printf("\%,2 d",points_total)
    +": pi = "
    +util.printf("\%,2 .9f",(4*points_inside/points_total))+"\\r";
rowA+=row;
}
f1.value=rowA;
\end{defineJS}

\begin{document}
\pushButton[\CA{Calculate Pi}\A{\JS{\myPi}}]{MCpi}{}{11bp} \qquad     \pushButton[\CA{Reset}\A{\JS{this.resetForm("PiField");}}]{reset}{1.5cm}{11bp}

\bigskip

\textField[\Ff{\FfMultiline}]{PiField}{8cm}{11bp*40}
\end{document}
```

[image]